# Regex check always return null\false\-1

Tags: javascript

I have a simple calculator on ASP.NET MVC5, front side is on HTML\CSS\Javascript. 
In event handlers for buttons I concatenate all values into a string and want to check if it satisfies the regex. But, for example, if I put following values into my calculator: '99*66-', the code below returns null every time.

Here regex works okay: https://regex101.com/r/AxMvPe/1

Whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/0g79hkbc/

```
var regEx = /[+-]?([0-9]*[,])?[0-9]+[-+\/*][0-9]*[,]?[0-9]+[-+\/*]/;    //in case if problems will appear https://regex101.com/ 

$('.button').on('click', function () {
  var buttonText = this.innerHTML;
  var inputedText = inputElement.innerHTML + buttonText;

  console.log(inputedText.match(regEx));

});
```

I have tried following options, but they didn't help:

1. to replace regex expression on Regex object
2. to use .test() instead of .match()  (got false)
3. to use .search() instead of .match()  (got -1)

I also tried to manually entered '99*66-' and then compare inputedText with javascript string '99*66-', it also returns false. Why?

Comment: random advice: please avoid using `innerHTML` and use `textContent` instead

Comment: random advice 2: always put `-` in front of character matchings. `[-+]`

Comment: If your regex works in isolation, but not inside of a function, then `inputedText` is probably not what you think it is. What is `inputedText` (console log it) when the regex test is false?

Comment: following code:

 `console.log('value: ' + inputedText + ' type: ' + typeof inputedText);

 console.log({inputedText});
` 
shows: http://prntscr.com/nk2ep4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me, except that it will not match when there is for example `99*`. You will need a repeating set of regex like: https://regex101.com/r/AxMvPe/2
Added floats to it :)

```js
var regEx = /[+-]?([0-9]*[,])?[0-9]+[-+\/*][0-9]*[,]?[0-9]+[-+\/*]/;    //in case if problems will appear 

inputElement = $('#input');

$('.button').on('click', function () {
  var buttonText = $(this).val();
  var inputedText = inputElement.val() + buttonText;
  
  console.log(inputedText.match(regEx));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input' type='text' value='99*66' />
<input class='button' type='button' value='-'/>
```

Comment: Thank you, the actual probleam indeed was with regex itself.
I also added ^ and & symbols at the start\end of the expression and changed .innerHtml property on .textContext property.
Now it works fine.